# Parse.com: Sending a localized push notification to Android client - what does the client implementation look like?

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, android-notifications, parse-cloud-code

I'm looking to do exactly what's described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26163121/parse-push-notification-language-with-cloud-code), but sending to an Android client. How does the Android client correctly handle the `loc-key`, `loc-args` and `action-loc-key` parameters in the `alert` object?

Cloud code:

```
Parse.Push.send({
        where: pushQuery,
        data: {
            title: title,
            alert: {
                    "loc-key":"msg",
                    "loc-args":["John"],
                    "action-loc-key":"rsp"
            },
            type: type
        }
    }
```

How can the Android client correctly handle those keys and localize the push? Do I have to manually subclass the Parse broadcast receiver?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to subclass the Parse Broadcast receiver

first, declare a receiver in your manifest

```
        <receiver android:name="com.example.PushReceiver" android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Then you create a ParsePushBroadcastReceiver subclass and override the onReceive method.

```
    public class PushReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver{
      @Override
      public void onPushReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));

         //This is where you get your values
          JSONObject alertObject = json.getJSONObject("alert");

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's more work than that. I'm an hour or so into this and I have to override the `getNotification` method too - which is annoying to do, because it builds the notification rather than leaving it in a Builder. So I can't modify the `alert` text on the Notification object it returns. Hmm. I might have to just copy the whole damn method and do the alert localization in there. Why does Parse make this so complicated?

Comment: By the way, the correct method to override is `onPushReceive`, not `onReceive` - but thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Sure, I don't know why is so complicated with parse, I've done it with GCM a couple time and the client part has been much easier